# Getting Trade Details from EtherDelta

Tags: transactions, etherdelta

It's tax time in Australia and I'm trying to get specific information from Etherscan of the trades I made on EtherDelta. I can track my deposits to and withdrawals from the EtherDelta contract address, but I'm having difficulty finding specifics of the trades I made. For example, I open up the deposit transaction and it just seems like a deadend... what happened after that? Is there a simple way to read details of the smart contracts via Etherscan? Also, is there any documentation about Etherscan and the information it displays?

Comment: what "specifics of the trade " do you need? Event logs is usually the fullest info about contract transaction. If you can define a specific requirement I can develop the report you need. I am working on an Ethereum wallet, so , user input is welcomed.

Comment: Hi Nulik, thanks for your response. For example, you transfer ETH to the ED contract address. Then you trade that ETH for OMG (for example). Then you withdraw the OMG from ED to your ETH address. All I can track on Etherscan is the ETH going into the ED contract address and the OMG coming out. There's no obvious way for me to see the actual trade that has occurred and I can't link the ETH going in with the OMG coming out. It would be good if there was some documentation about Etherscan and the information it's presenting. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looks like a very useful feature to have. I will consider it for the future development. If it is not a problem for you to give the transaction hash of the OMG going in, and OMG going out, that would be helpful as a use case.